# Conflict between gcc and clang when compiling a code on Mac Osx El Capitan

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc, gfortran, grib

I was compiling a code (wgrib) which needs C and Fortran. I have installed Xcode 7.3.1 and the relative command line tools for Xcode 7.3 on my MacOsx El Capitan. 
I'm pasting the command line and the config.log after compiling wgrib (which failed).

```
export CC=/usr/bin/gcc

export FC=/usr/local/bin/gfortran

sudo make wgrib
makefile:362: *** ERROR, fortran compiler (enironment vararible FC) is not recognized.  Stop.


vi config.log



 This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by libaec configure 1.0.0, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --disable-shared --prefix=/usr/local/grib2

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = IMac-Arianna.local
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 15.6.0
uname -s = Darwin
uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0: Fri Feb 17 10:21:18 PST 2017; root:xnu-3248.60.11.4.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = Mach kernel version:
         Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0: Fri Feb 17 10:21:18 PST 2017; root:xnu-3248.60.11.4.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel configured for up to 2 processors.
2 processors are physically available.
2 processors are logically available.
Processor type: i486 (Intel 80486)
Processors active: 0 1
Primary memory available: 4.00 gigabytes
Default processor set: 232 tasks, 903 threads, 2 processors
Load average: 4.19, Mach factor: 0.54
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin
PATH: /opt/local/bin
PATH: /opt/local/sbin
PATH: /opt/local/bin
PATH: /opt/local/sbin
PATH: /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs
PATH: /opt/local/bin
PATH: /opt/local/sbin
PATH: .
PATH: /Users/arianna/seadas6.1/scripts
PATH: /Users/arianna/seadas6.1/bin
PATH: .
PATH: /Users/arianna/seadas6.1/src/lib3/hdf4/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /opt/X11/bin
PATH: /Library/TeX/texbin
PATH: /Applications/itt/idl/idl80/bin/
## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2430: checking build system type
configure:2444: result: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
configure:2464: checking host system type
configure:2477: result: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
configure:2518: checking how to print strings
configure:2545: result: printf
configure:2617: checking for gcc
configure:2644: result: /usr/bin/gcc
configure:2873: checking for C compiler version
configure:2882: /usr/bin/gcc --version >&5
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
configure:2893: $? = 0
configure:2882: /usr/bin/gcc -v >&5
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
configure:2893: $? = 0
configure:2882: /usr/bin/gcc -V >&5
clang: error: argument to '-V' is missing (expected 1 value)
clang: error: no input files
configure:2893: $? = 1
configure:2882: /usr/bin/gcc -qversion >&5
clang: error: unknown argument: '-qversion'
clang: error: no input files
configure:2893: $? = 1
configure:2913: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:2935: /usr/bin/gcc -I/usr/local/grib2/include -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror=format-security --fast-math -O3 -DGFORTRAN -fopenmp -I/usr/local/grib2/jasper-1.900.1/src/libjasper/include -I/usr/include    conftest.c  >&5
clang: error: unsupported option '--fast-math'
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
configure:2939: $? = 1
configure:2977: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "libaec"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libaec"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.0.0"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "libaec 1.0.0"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "rosenhauer@dkrz.de"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
|
| int
| main ()
| {
|
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:2982: error: in `/usr/local/grib2/libaec-1.0.0':
configure:2984: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value=/usr/bin/gcc
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value='-I/usr/local/grib2/include -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror=format-security --fast-math -O3 -DGFORTRAN -fopenmp -I/usr/local/grib2/jasper-1.900.1/src/libjasper/include -I/usr/include '
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH_set=
ac_cv_env_LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR=''
AM_BACKSLASH=''
AM_DEFAULT_V=''
AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY=''
AM_V=''
AR=''
AUTOCONF=''
AUTOHEADER=''
AUTOMAKE=''
AWK=''
CC='/usr/bin/gcc'
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS='-I/usr/local/grib2/include -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror=format-security --fast-math -O3 -DGFORTRAN -fopenmp -I/usr/local/grib2/jasper-1.900.1/src/libjasper/include -I/usr/include '
CFLAG_VISIBILITY=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CYGPATH_W=''
DEFS=''
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p=''
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/usr/local/grib2'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
runstatedir='${localstatedir}/run'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/usr/local/grib2'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
runstatedir='${localstatedir}/run'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "libaec"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libaec"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.0.0"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "libaec 1.0.0"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "rosenhauer@dkrz.de"
#define PACKAGE_URL ""

configure: exit 77
```

Comment: Why do you call this conflict between clang and gcc? I don't see any clang anywhere.  What does `/usr/local/bin/gfortran -v` print?

Comment: This error has nothing to do with Fortran.  The error messages are "unsupported option '--fast-math'" and "unsupported option '-fopenmp'".  You will need to fix the broken makefile.  The correct flag is `-ffast-math` not `--fast-math`. You'll need to get OpenMP working on your computer.

Comment: The problem was effectively OpenMP. Now everything works! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You're using clang, not the GNU gcc, as noted by the output:

```
/usr/bin/gcc --version
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
```

libaec is known to have compatibility issues with clang, using the real gcc instead should fix your problem:

```
brew install gcc
export CC=gcc-9   # Use the version listed in `ls /usr/local/bin/gcc-*`, not clang gcc
export FC=gfortran
make
```